# How to create reusable classes in flutter for game design

Tags: flutter, class

I am trying to create "reusable classes" if that is the correct term to use here.

Let's say I am making a little game using tiles in a gridview.  I have something like this:

```
enum gridTileClass { goblin, elf, dragon, dungeonFloor1 }

class gridTileData {
  final gridTileClass type;
  late final String tileImage;
  int currentHealth;

  gridTileData({
    required this.type,
    required this.tileImage,
    required this.currentHealth,
  });
}
```

But then when I am setting up the board, I am having to enter the data for every space on the grid manually, like this:

```
List<List<gridTileData?>> initializeBoard(int currentLevel) {
  newBoard[0][0] = gridTileData(
    type: gridTileClass.dungeonFloor1,
    tileImage: './lib/images/dungeon_tile_1.png',
    currentHealth: 0,
  );
  newBoard[0][1] = gridTileData(
    type: gridTileClass.dungeonFloor1,
    tileImage: './lib/images/dungeon_tile_1.png',
    currentHealth: 0,
  );
  newBoard[0][2] = gridTileData(
    type: gridTileClass.goblin,
    tileImage: './lib/images/goblin1.png',
    currentHealth: 0,
  );
  newBoard[0][3] = gridTileData(
    type: gridTileClass.goblin,
    tileImage: './lib/images/goblin1.png',
    currentHealth: 0,
  );
}
```

Now this is a simplified example, in reality it is far more tedious because I have instead of 3 properties for a class, more like 20 or more.

I would love to be able to instead do something like:

```
newBoard[0][1] = goblin;
```

somehow, since I have told it what a goblin is previously somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `factory` to pre-defined the class's properties.

```
class gridTileData {
  final gridTileClass type;
  final String tileImage;
  int currentHealth;

  gridTileData({
    required this.type,
    required this.tileImage,
    required this.currentHealth,
  });

  factory gridTileData.goblin() {
    return gridTileData(
      type: gridTileClass.goblin,
      tileImage: './lib/images/goblin1.png',
      currentHealth: 0,
    );
  }

  factory gridTileData.elf() {
    return gridTileData(
      type: gridTileClass.elf,
      tileImage: './lib/images/elf1.png',
      currentHealth: 0,
    );
  }

  factory gridTileData.dungeonFloor1() {
    return gridTileData(
      type: gridTileClass.dungeonFloor1,
      tileImage: './lib/images/dungeon_tile_1.png',
      currentHealth: 0,
    );
  }
  
  //TODO More type...
}
```

And usage:

```
newBoard[0][1] = gridTileData.dungeonFloor1();
```

Comment: Perfect mate, the factory worked fine.  Excellent solution.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use the **Builder** design pattern

you will be able to do something like this:

```
newBoard[0][1] = GoblinBuilder.build();
```

and the code for Builder and GoblinBuilder will be:

```
abstract class Builder{
    gridTileData builder();
}

class GoblinBuilder extends Builder{
    @override    
    gridTileData builder(){
       return gridTileData(
          type: gridTileClass.goblin,
          tileImage: './lib/images/goblin1.png',
          currentHealth: 0,
       );
    }
}
```

you can do the same for other characters and more.

for more info about the builder design pattern :

- https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/builder
- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/builder-design-pattern/

Comment: I am sure this solution would have worked just as well as the above, I just went with the Factory method.  Thank you very much for your suggestion!